# Can't get this JOIN to work

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Basically my problem is the following. I got this query:

```
select 
  ROUND(((SUM(1/Pl))/Count(*))*100, 1) as 'ExpectedWinrate', 
  Players.Pname as 'Player' 
from 
  Wins, Players 
where Code like CONCAT('%', Players.SC, '%') 
Group by Players.Pname 
Order by ROUND(((SUM(1/Pl))/Count(*))*100, 1) desc;
```

And it works the way I want it to (computes the Expected Winrate of several Players in a Multiplayer Card Game over several games).
My Problem is now that I want to join the table I get out of it with another table I get from this query:

```
select 
  Count(*) as 'Wins', 
  Players.Pname as 'Player' 
from Players, Wins 
where Players.PNr = Wins.PNr 
group by Players.Pname 
order by Count(*) desc;
```

As far as I know to do that I have to use JOIN but I simply can't get it to work. 
In alpha Language the thing I want to do is:

```
JOIN query_1 AND query_2 over PName;
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM query_1 JOIN query_2 ON query_1.PName = query_2.PName` Or just combine the queries.

Comment: 1) your joined tables can only have one order by unless they are created as sub queries.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
SELECT a.'Player',a.'ExpectedWinrate',b.'Wins'
FROM(
SELECT  
  ROUND(((SUM(1/Pl))/Count(*))*100, 1) as 'ExpectedWinrate', 
  Players.Pname as 'Player' 
FROM 
  Wins, Players 
WHERE Code LIKE CONCAT('%', Players.SC, '%') 
GROUP BY Players.Pname) a
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT 
  Count(*) as 'Wins', 
  Players.Pname as 'Player' 
FROM Players, Wins 
WHERE Players.PNr = Wins.PNr 
GROUP BY Players.Pname 
ORDER BY Count(*) desc) b ON a.'Player' = b.'Player'
```

Comment: That was basically what I was looking for only that I get:
You have an Error in your mysql syntax, check [..] to use near ''Player', a.'ExpectedWinrate',...

Comment: Can you paste some example data ?

Comment: The Table "Players" contains the PlayerNr, the Playername (Pname) and the Playertag (SC) so it contains tuples like this:
...,2  Tobias  T, 3 Marty M, ...

"Wins" contains the PNr of the Winner(Magic the Gathering) the DeckNr of the Winner, the Date, how many players played, and a Code consisting of the Tags of the players who played in the game:
...,3  21  2014-08-14  5  TMAVH,...

So basically what I get out of those two querys is one table with expected Winrate and name e.g.:
...53%  Marty, 41% Tobias,...
and one with number of wins and name:
...7 Marty, 4 Tobias,...

(sry 'bout formating)